# Failed to load the runtime error when deploying with ClickOnce

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have created a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application with Visual Studio 2010 targeting .NET 2.0. I am deploying it using ClickOnce, and it has installed successfully on all machines except once. Most of our machines are Windows XP 64, and the application has installed on all of them except on this specific machine.

I have checked that this machine has .NET 2.0, 3.5 SP1 & 4.0. Yet the deployment fails with the following error:

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>
> Windows             : 5.2.3790.131072
>   (Win32NT)
>
> Common Language Runtime     :
>   4.0.30319.1
>
> System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1
>   (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>
> clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1
>   (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>
> dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1
>   (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>
> dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0
>   (Main.031106-0000)
>
> SOURCES
>
> Deployment url          :
>   file:///WrpApp/WRPDatatEntry.application
>
> Deployment Provider url     :
>   file:///WrpApp/WRPDatatEntry.application
>
> Application url         :
>   file:///WrpApp/Application%20Files/WRPDatatEntry_0_2_1_4/WRPDatatEntry.exe.manifest
>
> IDENTITIES
>
> Deployment Identity     :
>   WRPDatatEntry.application,
>   Version=0.2.1.4, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=dcbea49d7f78e494,
>   processorArchitecture=x86
>
> Application Identity        :
>   WRPDatatEntry.exe, Version=0.2.1.4,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=dcbea49d7f78e494,
>   processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY
>
> - Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY
>
> Below is a summary of the errors,
>   details of these errors are listed
>   later in the log.
>
> - Activation of
>     \\WrpApp\WRPDatatEntry.application
>     resulted in exception. Following
>     failure messages were detected:
>
>   - Failed to load the runtime.
>       (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE
>   SUMMARY
>
> No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>
> There were no warnings during this
>   operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:00 AM] : Activation
>     of
>     \\WrpApp\WRPDatatEntry.application
>     has started.
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:00 AM] : Processing
>     of deployment manifest has
>     successfully completed.
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:00 AM] :
>     Installation of the application has
>     started.
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:00 AM] : Processing
>     of application manifest has
>     successfully completed.
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:02 AM] : Found
>     compatible runtime version 2.0.50727.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>
> Following errors were detected during
>   this operation.
>
> - [6/30/2011 9:53:02 AM]
>     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
>   - Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)
>   - Source: System.Deployment
>   - Stack trace:
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.IClrMetaHostPolicy.GetRequestedRuntime(MetaHostPolicyFlags
>       policyFlags, String binaryPath,
>       IStream configStream, StringBuilder
>       version, Int32& versionLength,
>       StringBuilder imageVersion, Int32&
>       imageVersionLength, Int32&
>       pdwConfigFlags, Guid interfaceId)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.GetAssemblyCacheInterface(String
>       CLRVersionString, Boolean
>       FetchRuntimeHost, CCorRuntimeHost&
>       RuntimeHost)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.PlatformDetector.VerifyPlatformDependencies(AssemblyManifest
>       appManifest, AssemblyManifest
>       deployManifest, String tempDir)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>       subState, ActivationDescription
>       actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>       TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>       subState, ActivationDescription
>       actDesc)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>       activationUri, Boolean isShortcut,
>       String textualSubId, String
>       deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension,
>       BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>       String& errorPageUrl)
>
>     at
>       System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>       state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>
> No transaction information is
>   available.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous references to this error if you google the error code [0x80131700](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=10&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=0x80131700&qe=MHg4MDEzMTcwMA&qesig=fpPUM76OiD_QabyZZaugeg&pkc=AFgZ2tman5S5ZX6quUOAcdEDYqUG3gzaB5_GAbytiyES5D_IhAYYJzoy7w5psWjwHEtbbQH2OqRAk3Z8ma0HGCBBTLK_WM4IlA&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=0x80131700&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=733c9000aadb1943&biw=1680&bih=922).

The resolution appears to be downloading and installing the latest .NET Framework. I know you've mentioned that you've already done that. Step #2 should be uninstall all of the .NET Frameworks and service packs that you can uninstall, restart the PC (if it doesn't force you to do so) and then re-install all of the Frameworks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) exception. Does your application use the Office Primary Interop assemblies, and if so, are you including those in your deployment as a prerequisite? If it's not Office, do you have some other kind of COM component that isn't being installed correctly?

Comment: I am using the Excel Interop namespace, But I am not deploying those assemblies. The same version of Microsoft Office (2010) exists on the deployment machine. What do you suggest?

Comment: If your application targets .NET 4 and Office 2010, you do not have to install the Primary Interop Assemblies. If you are targeting .NET 3.5 and Office 2007 and/or Office 2010, you need to install the Office PIA's on the machine. You can do that manually, but it would be good also (or instead) to select the Primary Interop Assemblies as a prerequisite in the list of prerequisites. You may also need the VSTO runtime, but that might be included in the Office 2010 install, I can't remember.